# TransactionRollbackError: could not serialize access due to concurrent update

Tags: odoo, etl, odoo-8

I am using odoo etl tool which I got from odoo apps to migrate my database to 8th version.After entering the details, when I start migration process I am getting this error.Any help would be appreciated.

```
TransactionRollbackError: could not serialize access due to concurrent update

CONTEXT: SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."res_users" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x"
```

Comment: Do you have code on github?

Comment: No i downloaded form offcial odoo apps here is the link,https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/etl/

Comment: Did you solve this error ?

Comment: ya, when one sql query is giving error and immediately when another query is executed it gives error like this. Need to rollback the sql command which gives error